# Recognizing euler's constant (e) only when relevant

Tags: antlr4

I'm learning ANTLR4 to write a parser for a simple language specific to the app developed by the company. So far I've managed to have working arithmetic operations, logic operations, and conditional branchments. When tackling variables though, I ran into a problem. The language defines multiple mathematical constants, such as 'e'. When parsing variables, the parser would recognize the letter e as the constant and not part of the variable.

Below is a small test grammar I wrote to test this specific case, the euler and letter parser rules are there for visual clarity in the trees below

```
grammar Test; r: str '\r\n' EOF;
str: euler | (letter)* ;
euler: EULER;
letter: LETTER;
EULER: 'e';
LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
```

Recognition of different strings with this grammar:

> ["e"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECxqE.png)
> ["test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdykE.png)
> ["qsdf"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoXNo.png)
> ["eee"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sJkw.png)

I thought maybe parser rule precedence had something to do with it, but whatever order the parser rules are in, the output is the same. Swapping the lexer rules allows for correct recognition of "test", but recognizes "e" using the letter rule and not the euler rule. I also thought about defining EULER as:
`EULER: ~[a-zA-Z] 'e' ~[a-zA-Z]`
but this wouldn't recognize `var a=e` correctly. Another rule i have in my lexer is the `ELSE: 'else'` rule, which recognizes the 'else' keyword, which works and doesn't conflict with rule EULER. This is because antlr recognizes the longest input possible, but then why doesn't it recognize "test" as `(r (str (letter t) (letter e) (letter s) (letter t)) \r\n <EOF>)` as it would for "qsdf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a lexer rule like `LETTER` that matches a single letter and then "glue" these letters together in a parser rule. Instead, match a variable (consisting of multiple letters) as a single lexer rule:

```
EULER: 'e';
VARIABLE: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your grammar to this:

```
grammar Test;

r: str '\n' EOF;
str: euler | WORD ;
euler: EULER;

EULER: 'e';
WORD: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears you wanted a stand-alone "e" to be an `euler` element, and any other word to be a `letter` element, but that's not what you coded.  Your grammar is doing exactly what you told it to do: Match every "e" as an EULER token (and therefore an `euler` element), and any other letter as a LETTER token (and therefore a `letter` element), and build `str`s out of those two tokens.

An ANTLR4 lexer tokenizes the input stream, trying to build the longest tokens possible, and processing the tokenization rules in the order you code them.  Thus `EULER` will capture every "e", and `LETTER` will capture "a"-"d", "f"-"z", and "A"-"Z".  An ANTLR4 parser maps the stream of tokens (from the lexer) into elements based on the order of tokens and the rules you code.  Since the parser will never get a `LETTER` token for "e", your `str` elements will always get chopped apart at the "e"s.

The fix for this is to code a lexer rule that collects sequences of letters that aren't stand-alone "e"s into a `LETTER` token (or, as @pavel-ganelin says, a `WORD`), and to present that to the parser instead of the individual letters.  It's a little more complicated than that, though, becuase you probably want "easy" to be the `WORD` "easy", not an `EULER` ("e") followed by the `WORD` "asy".  So, you need to ensure that the "e" starting a string of letters isn't captured as an `EULER` token.  You do that by ensuring that the `WORD` lexer rule comes before the `EULER` rule, and that it ignores stand-alone "e"s:

```
grammar Test;

r:     str '\r\n' EOF;
str:   euler | word ;
euler: EULER;
word:  WORD;
WORD:  ('e' [a-zA-Z]+) | [a-zA-Z]+;
EULER: 'e';
```

Comment: The token EULER will now never be matched because a single ‘e’ will now be matched as a WORD.

Comment: This is clearly a fragment of a larger grammar.  I assumed other tokens would be present, and whitespace, which would isolate an EULER from a WORD.  But yes, if these are the only rules, the entire input will be lexed as a single `WORD` token.

Comment: My point is, the rule `EULER: 'e';` might as well be removed from your example grammar since it can never match. And `('e' [a-zA-Z]+)` can also be removed from `WORD` since `[a-zA-Z]+` would already match the same.